# pronunciation of -ed in "discharged on"

Tags: pronunciation

> "the gun discharg**ed** on its own during the struggle"

How is *d* pronounced here? Is it like [t] or like [d] (especially given that the following word "on" starts with a vowel sound)?

Neither Webster, nor Cambridge, nor Collins provide pronunciation transcriptions for "ed" in the end of some verbs' past forms.

Comment: If you're having difficulty pronouncing the '....ged' part, you can substitute /ʒ/ for /d͡ʒ/ as I explained in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266496/106592) so 'discharged on' becomes [dɪst͡ʃɑːr**ʒd** ɒn]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pronounced [d]. The bridge between the [dʒ] and the [d] may be difficult for native speakers of languages that lack the [dʒ] sound or that avoid combinations of consonants.

Comment: Difficult for native speakers???

Comment: @brilliant read the rest of the sentence?

Comment: Ah! I got it. Thank you.